# Alternative to field group module

Tags: 9

The field group module is currently not ready for Drupal 9. I would like to implement the same functionality for my forms. What other alternative module can I use that is compatible with Drupal 9, PHP 7.4, and MySQL 8?

Comment: What does this have to do with webforms?

Comment: As Kevin said, the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module is definitely D9 ready.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 4):

Field Group ***does*** work with Drupal 9. There is no alternative.